# Mount Bitrix24 drive: legacy Digest challenge not supported

Tags: ubuntu, mount, davfs2

I would like to mount a bitrix24 network drive.
The drive seems to be accessible via webDAV using a URL that looks like the following:
`https://b24-XXXXXX.bitrix24.de/company/personal/user/1/disk/path/` with XXXXXX as a random ASCII string.

While my final aim would be to mount the drive automatically via fstab, I worked out the following command for initial attempts:

```bash
sudo mount -t davfs https://b24-XXXXXX.bitrix24.de/company/personal/user/1/disk/path/
```

After initiating the command the following procedure with the corresponding error message is triggered:

```bash
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://b24-XXXXXX.bitrix24.de/company/personal/user/1/disk/path/ or hit enter for none.
  Username: username@domain.tld
Please enter the password to authenticate user andreas@weinzierl.it with server
https://b24-XXXXXX.bitrix24.de/company/personal/user/1/disk/path/ or hit enter for none.
  Password:
/sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
Could not authenticate to server: legacy Digest challenge not supported
```

Sadly, it isn't really apparent how I could fix this problem from the client side.
I would like to note that adding the same drive with the same credentials in `Windows Explorer` works fine, which means that in theory mounting should be possible.

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" (via WSL 2)